# What is this weird character and why is it here?

Tags: html, css

Reading a [Bloomberg article](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2019-07-13/the-black-hole-engulfing-the-world-s-bond-markets-quicktake) about the bond market and I see this strange character as part of a link:

[image]

I tried to copy and paste it into vim where I could examine it more closely, but I am not able to select it with my mouse:

[image]

If I inspect the element, then it shows up as "::after" within a `<a>` tag.

[image]
[image]

Is this even text at all, is it unicode? Why does my browser replace the text "::after" with this symbol?

Browser: Firefox Quantum 68.0.1 (64-bit)

OS: macOS Mojave 10.14.5

Comment: Its an icon, that's all.

Comment: `::after` isn't text; it's the DOM inspector's representation of the [`::after` CSS pseudo-element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdM13.png). As for what the icon means: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdM13.png

Comment: Ohhhhh thanks for sharing that image, that makes a lot of sense - I wasn't seeing the bar at the footer on my screen. The double empty squares in the character looked like the old school □ I used to see when a glyph was not found, so I assumed it meant something similar.

Answer (score 2):

They are using an svg icon by the external link. This is defined purely in css using `:after` pseudo-selector. You can inspect it in Dev Tools - it looks like this:

```
.body-copy a.terminal-news-story::after {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 16px;
    margin: 0 0 -4px 5px;
    content: "";
    background: no-repeat url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIGlkPSJMYXllcl8xIiB4bWxuc…MuOS0zLjlMMTAwLjMsMy45eiBNOTUuNywzOEg1Ny4xIFY0LjZoMzguNlYzOHoiLz48L3N2Zz4=);
}
```